# Button Listener adding and removing objects from a list

Tags: java, swing, compiler-errors, awt, actionlistener

I'm trying to create a tab for an applet that can uses pet types from another tab.  This tab has the available pet types on the left, and the added pet types on the right.  A user can add a pet to the right column by electing it in the left column then clicking the add button, or remove a pet from the right column by selecting it and clicking on the remove button.  I can't figure out how to get the program to do this though, and keep getting errors.  Here is my code.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;
import java.util.*;

public class SelectPanel extends JPanel
 {
   private Vector petList, selectList;
   private Panel bPanel, nPanel;
   private JLabel sPets, aPets, nPets;
   private int numPets = 0;
   private JButton addPet, remove;
   private JList petsAvail, petTypes;
   private JScrollPane sPane, sPane2;

   public SelectPanel(Vector petList)
     {
      this.petList = petList;
  this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

  bPanel = new Panel();
  nPanel = new Panel();
  nPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,2));
  bPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(2,1));

  petTypes = new JList(petList);
  petTypes.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
  sPane = new JScrollPane(petTypes);

  selectList = new Vector();
  petsAvail = new JList(selectList);
  petsAvail.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
  sPane2 = new JScrollPane(petsAvail);
  selectList.add(0, "Selected pet(s)");

  aPets = new JLabel("Available pet(s)");
  nPets = new JLabel("Selected pet(s)");
  nPets = new JLabel("The number of selected pets:" + numPets);
  addPet = new JButton("Add");
  remove = new JButton("Remove");

  add(petsAvail, BorderLayout.EAST);
  add(petTypes, BorderLayout.WEST);
  add(nPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
  nPanel.add(nPets);
  add(bPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
  bPanel.add(addPet);
  bPanel.add(remove);

  addPet.addActionListener(new ButtonListener());
  remove.addActionListener(new ButtonListener());


 // orgranize components for the panel


 }

 public void updatePetList()
  {
        petTypes.updateUI();
        //This method can refresh the appearance of the list of pets
        //by calling updateUI() method for the JList.
        //It can be called from the CreatePanel class whenever a new pet type
        //is added to the vector and the JList appearence needs to be refreshed.
  }

 private class ButtonListener implements ActionListener
  {
       public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
        {
            Object which = event.getSource();

        if(which == addPet){
            for (int p = 1; p < selectList.size(); p++){
                boolean check = false;
                String selectedPet =(String) petList.getSelectedValue();
                String petCheck =(String) selectList.get(p);
                if(selectedPet.equals(petCheck)){
                    check = true;
                    break;
                } else if(added == false){
                    petsAvail.add(selectedPet);
                    petsAvail.updateUI();
                    numPets++;
                }
            }
        } else if (which == remove){

            numPets--;
        }



        //When the added button is pushed, the selected pet
        //should be added to the right list and the number of
        //selected pets is incremented by 1.
        //When the remove button is pushed, the selected pet
        //should be removed from the right list and the number of
        //selected pets is decremented by 1.
        //
        //Be careful for the cases when no item has been selected.
    }
  } //end of ButtonListener class

} //end of SelectPanel class
```

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

The errors are:

```
C:\Users\[Redacted]\Desktop\Java\SelectPanel.java:83: error: cannot find symbol
                String selectedPet =(String) petList.getSelectedValue();
                                                    ^


 symbol:   method getSelectedValue()
  location: variable petList of type Vector
C:\Users\[Redacted]\Desktop\Java\SelectPanel.java:89: error: no suitable method found for add(String)
                        petsAvail.add(selectedPet);
                                 ^

method Container.add(Component,Object,int) is not applicable
      (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
    method Container.add(Component,Object) is not applicable
      (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
    method Container.add(Component,int) is not applicable
      (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
    method Container.add(String,Component) is not applicable
      (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
    method Container.add(Component) is not applicable
      (actual argument String cannot be converted to Component by method invocation conversion)
    method Component.add(PopupMenu) is not applicable
      (actual argument String cannot be converted to PopupMenu by method invocation conversion)
Note: C:\Users\[Redacted]\Desktop\Java\SelectPanel.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
2 errors

Tool completed with exit code 1
```

Comment: If necessary, I can add the 2 other java documents used in the applet, but those 2 work fine.  Its just this one throwing up errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to call methods that simply don't exist, and the compiler is rightly complaining. Your petlist is a Vector variable, and if you look at the Vector API you'll see what methods are available for this type.  The method `getSelectedValue()` is not one of them and really makes little sense for a Vector.

Likewise Vector's don't have an `add(...)` method. Again, please get very familiar with the [Java API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/) as it will help prevent you from making these sorts of errors.

Comment: Then what can be used to do what I'm trying to do?  I'm trying to learn Java, so I appreciate you informing me that the add() and getSelectedValue() methods don't work with vectors, but telling me to 'get very familiar' with the Java API was not as helpful.

Comment: @user2032938: Please you are not in a position to say that the suggestions "are not helpful". Seriously. If you are going to be wanting to learn to code in Java, you must learn to go there first, and do it well. The more you use the API, the better your skill will be in using it. This is likely the best advice you will get from this question, and if you stick with Java for more than a semester, you will soon realize that this is so.

Comment: *"telling me to 'get very familiar' with the Java API was not as helpful"*  I disagree.  Or rather, I disagree it is not a useful suggestion.  I must have consulted those docs over 40 times today, and I've been coding Java for over a decade.

Comment: I've looked over the API, but it hasn't done anything to explain why the code still isn't working.  Even after changing the methods to Vector appropriate methods, it still errors, and I don't know why.  So looking at the API has not been very helpful.

Comment: @user2032938: The problem is not that the API isn't helpful, but rather that you are as yet unfamiliar with using the API and getting the information from it that you need. It lists ***all*** the methods available for all the core Java classes. So if the compiler tells you that a method that you're trying to use isn't available, the API will tell you *exactly* what is. Again, keep trying to use it, because the better you get at using it, the more helpful it will be. Right now you're trying to make up methods and pray that they'll work, and that's a recipe for disaster.

Comment: I think I understand the methods I need to use, but what I don't understand is how to I get the program to call upon the highlighted object in one of the lists?

Comment: *"I think I understand the methods I need to use"*  The compiler output suggests otherwise.

Comment: @user2032938: then one problem is that you're calling a method on the *wrong* object. You don't want the selected item from the VEctor but rather from the JList. That's a different variable. Fix that.

Comment: That would be because I don't know how to call upon the object the user selects in the lists.  I have changed the methods in my program, but can't figure out how to call upon the object the use has highlighted.

Comment: @Hovercraft Full Of Eels: Okay, I got the add button working.  Thank you for your help.  I didn't realize I didn't want the selected item from the Vector.  Now, to try and work on the remove button.

Comment: Okay, this may seem stupid, what does it mean if the program 'uses unchecked or unsafe operations"?  I thought it meant one of your object names was bad, but after checking through it, I can't find what would give that error.

Comment: @user2032938: this is likely because your JList was not generic. What does it hold? Strings? If so, then perhaps you would like to declare it as a `JList<String>` and initialize it likewise, `new JList<String>(petList)` and `new JList<String>(selectList)`

Answer (score 0):

If I were writing similar code, I would probably use ArrayLists instead of Vectors. If you have a debugger, it would be best to debug the code so you can see what each line of code is doing and find out at which point it fails. Sometimes, error codes are not reliable in determining the problem.

Comment: That gives error: cannot find symbol
      petsAvail.addElement(selectedPet);
               ^
  symbol:   method addElement(String)
  location: variable petsAvail of type JList